# Solution of the Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

> What are the possible triples (x,y,z) in positive integers such >that,
>
> $$(x+y)^{2}+3x+y+1=z^{2}$$

I have used the inequality approach and many others but wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: Hint: Let $t=(x+y)$

Comment: There are infinite many solutions. You can see this by putting  $x = -y$ so that the equation reduces to $2x + 1 = z^2$. This one requires that $z$ be odd so putting $z=2k+1$ one gets $x=2k^2+k$ and $y=-2k^2-k$ where k is any integer.

Comment: You can not do that since $x,y$ are natural. @Salcio

Comment: OK, then $k$ is a natural number ...

Comment: ???????? $$x=X-y$$ $$X^2+3X-2y=z^2$$ $$y=\frac{1}{2}(X^2-z^2)+X$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t:=x+y$ so that the Diophantine equation is equivalent to
$$t^2+t+2x+1=z^2.$$
In particular this shows that $z$ is odd, say $z=2s+1$. Multiplying by $4$ yields
$$(4s+2)^2=4z^2=4t^2+4t+8x+4=(2t+1)^2+8x+3,$$
and a bit of rearranging then shows that
$$(4s+2)^2-(2t+1)^2=8x+3.$$
Conversely, for any pair of integers $s$ and $t$ we have
$$(4s+2)^2-(2t+1)^2\equiv3\pmod{8},$$
which shows that the integral solutions are parametrized by
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x,y,z)
&=&\left(\frac{(4s+2)^2-(2t+1)^2-3}{8},t-\frac{(4s+2)^2-(2t+1)^2-3}{8},2s+1\right)\\
&=&\left(2s^2+2s-\frac{t^2+t}{2},-2s^2-2s+\frac{t^2-t}{2},2s+1\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inequalities should be implemented. Let $t=x+y$ then we have $$z^2 = t^2+t+1+2x$$

Notice that $0<x<t$ so we have $$t^2< t^2+t+1+2x <t^2+4t+4$$ which means $$t^2<z^2<(t+2)^2\implies z=t+1$$ Putting this in OP we get $$t =2x\implies x=y$$

So we have infinte triples, for each $x\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $(x,x,2x+1)$